# Email address validation based on domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email-validation

how do I write a regular expression to filter out email addresses in asp.net mvc?
I would like in example to allow users registering email addresses only if coming from microsoft.com domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `MailAddress` class:

```
MailAddress address = null;
try {
    address = new MailAddress(str);
} catch(FormatException) {
    //Invalid address
}
if (!address.Host.Equals("microsoft.com", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    //Bad domain
}
```

Comment: Thanks!How do I connect this function to a typical model in MVC with data annotations?

Comment: @Francesco: You'd need to write your own attribute.  If you really want a regex, you can use `.+@microsoft\.com$`